# Perfect Squares Python

Tags: python, oop

I have been trying to write a code that is suppose to return perfect squares using Object Oriented Programming from given values from a instance variable. Below is what I have written and still I was was not able to get perfect squares. Below is what I have written

```py
# Write a class, PerfectSquares, that implements an iterator
# This will return 1, 4, 9, 25, 36, 49, etc

class PerfectSquares:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        
    def get_values(self):
        return self.x**2

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in values:
    getter = values.get_values(i)
    print(getter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement both `__iter__` and `__next__` methods.

Iterator objects in python conform to the iterator protocol, which basically means they provide two methods: `__iter__` and `__next__`.

- The **iter** returns the iterator object and is implicitly called at the start of loops.
- The **next**() method returns the next value and is implicitly called at each loop increment. This method raises a StopIteration exception when there are no more value to return, which is implicitly captured by looping constructs to stop iterating.

A good resource for iterators: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pycon/

```
class PerfectSquares:
    """Class to implement an iterator
    of perfect squares"""

    def __init__(self, k):
        self.k = k
        self.n = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.n += 1
        if self.n <= self.k:
            result = self.n ** 2
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
v = PerfectSquares(10)
for i in v:
    print(i)
```

This will output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

Comment: Why make it an iterator? And this iterator is not implemented according to the specification.

Comment: " If required, some initialization can be performed." It probably shouldn't. The source you are quoting seems not very good.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is based on the spec, I was referring to the comment part (since I assumed that some got missed when writing the question). I chose to apply the length of the return values, but this is only to gave the user an idea

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga regarding the source, I coppied a small part from the link I supplied.
Can you refer to a better source, I will update the answer.

Comment: It is definitely not correctly implementing an iterator according to the specification. The big problem is the `self.n = 0` in `__iter__`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I missed that, it should start from 1. But can you point if there is other issues?

Comment: No, the problem is that it is *resetting it every time you call `__iter__`*. That isn't how iterators are supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

1. First, You have to **create an Object of the class** and pass value.
   (obj = PerfectSquares(i))
2. Second, Call the get_values method with that obj **without passing any
   arguments**, because get_values is not taking any.
3. Third, **print** the variable.

**Refer the code below:**

```
class PerfectSquares:
    def __init__(self, x): # this constructor takes an argument 'x'.
        self.x = x
        
    def get_values(self): # this function takes no argument.
        return self.x**2

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in values:
    obj = PerfectSquares(i) # 'i' variable is passed to 'x' in class.
    getter = obj.get_values() # returns the square of 'i' ('x' in class).
    print(getter)
```

**Output:**

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```